# How to get Ufraw to pass on EXIF data to Gimp

Tags: metadata, gimp, ufraw

I cannot find EXIF data in Gimp using Ufraw as standalone OR plug in, even though I use the option save EXIF data - what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that many image editors modify and even delete metadata, and I am not surprised that Ufraw does that too. One way to transfer metadata from the original to the processed image is to use the very flexible ExifTool. It's a simple executable that runs on many platforms and has tons of features. Check it out [here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

The basic command to copy metadata in your case would be something like this:

```
exiftool -tagsFromFile IMG_1234.CR2 IMG_1234.jpg
```